# Connect Windows to Multiple Androids via Wi-Fi Direct using VB.Net

Tags: android, vb.net, windows, networking

I want to create a small wireless network with a Windows 8.1 laptop as the "hub," connected to up to 8 Android devices.  I need to transfer files in both directions, between the laptop and the devices.

This needs to be a system that requires minimal setup since it will be distributed to the laptop owners.  The developer will not be available to help.  Minimal hardware and software requirements can be specified, but not actual models of laptops and devices.

It seems to me that Wi-Fi Direct is the best option to do this.  I know VB.Net best, so I would like to use that for development.  Does anyone have sample code that could get me started?  Would I also need an app to run on the devices to set up the pairing and network?

Thanks!